# Getting Google Analytics to track redirects from my site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics query I am using the SEMeasy Double Agent plugin on my Wordpress site to redirect visitors to particular pages to certain external sites. The plugin detects if a visitor is using a mobile device or desktop. If desktop, it overlays the external site without redirecting so these visitors can be tracked via Google Analytics. But with mobile users, it redirects the visitor to the external page before Google Analytics registers the visit. My question is: can I change the code of my site so that Google Analytics registers this click before redirecting to the external site? Sorry but I have very limited coding experience, so simple answers would be great!

Comment: Can we see your code example please?
Of cause it is possible to track such  events in analytics. 
To do so, you have to manage the click event with java script and or implement a tracking proxy site wich is handle the tracking before you send the user to the destination site.